# Implementing a map_keys_iterator by derivation: a single compiler error

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, iterator

I was working again with C++ during the weekend and came to notice something that I'm not sure where does it come from.

[Following the advice in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443793/iterate-keys-in-a-c-map), I decided to implement a `map_keys_iterator` and `map_values_iterator`. I took the -- I think -- recommended-against approach of deriving a class from `std::map<K,V>::iterator` and implementing it as such:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
struct map_values_iterator:
public std::map<K,V>::iterator {
  // explicitly call base's constructor
  typedef typename std::map<K,V>::iterator mIterator;
  map_values_iterator (const mIterator& mi) : 
  mIterator(mi) {};

  const V& operator* () const { return (*this)->second; }
};
```

So far, so good, and the following code works (nvm the Unicode, I default to work with i18n-capable terminals):

```
typedef std::map<double,string> Map;
Map constants;
constants[M_PI] = "π";
constants[(1+sqrt(5))/2] = "φ";
constants[exp(M_PI)-M_PI] = "fake_20";
// ... fill map with more constants!
map_values_iterator<double, std::string> vs(constants.begin());
for (; vs != m.end(); ++vs) { 
    cout<< (vs != m.begin() ? ", " : "")<< *vs;
    }
cout<< endl;
```

This code prints the expected result, something like (because a Map's elements are ordered):

```
..., φ, ..., π, ...., fake_20, ....
```

So I'd guess a `map_keys_iterator` would work in a similar way as well. I took the care that a Map's value_type is actually `pair<const K, V>` so the *keys* version will return a value.

However, it is unwieldly to have to declare the iterator's type so I wanted to create a caller with the classical `make_pair`-like idiom. And this is where trouble begins:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
map_values_iterator<K,V> map_values(const typename std::map<K,V>::iterator &i) {
    return lpp::map_values_iterator<K,V> (i);
}

template <typename K, typename V>
map_values_iterator<K,V> map_values(const typename std::map<K,V>::const_iterator &i) {
    return lpp::map_values_iterator<K,V> (i);
}
```

I'm relatively sure this function has the right signature and constructor invocation. However if I attempt to call the function from code:

```
auto vs= map_values(constants.begin());
```

I get a single STL compiler error of the form:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘map_values(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const double, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)’
```

I'm assuming here that in this particular case the whole `_Rb_tree_iterator` is actually the correct iterator for which `map::iterator` is typedefed; I'm not completely sure however. I've tried to provide more overloads to see if one of them matches (drop the reference, drop the const, use only non-const_iterator variants, etc) but so far nothing allows the signature I'm interested in.

If I store the base iterator in a variable before calling the function (as in `auto begin= constans.begin(); auto vs= map_values(begin);`) I get the exact same base error, only the description of the unmatched call is obviously different (in that it is a "const blah&").

My first attempt at implementing this sort of iterator was by creating a base class that aggregated `map::iterator` instead of inheriting, and deriving two classes, each with the adequate `operator*`, but that version ran into many more problems than the above and still forced me to replicate too much of the interface. So I tried this option for code-expedition.

I've tried to look for answers to this issue but my Google-fu isn't very strong today. Maybe I am missing something obvious, maybe I forgot something with the derivation (although I'm almost sure I didn't -- iterators are unlike containers), maybe I am actually required to specify all the template parameters for the map, or maybe my compiler is broken, but whatever it is I can't find it and I am having real trouble understanding what is the *actual* thing the compiler is complaining about here. In my previous experience, if you are doing something wrong with the STL you are supposed to see a diarrhoea of errors, not only **one** (which isn't STL to boot).

So... any (well-encapsulated) pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use your own implementation for that (did you had anything custom?) because if there is not one aldready on this site (I think I might have saw one though), I should have an implementation (very basic) of a map_key_iterator using boost::iterator_adaptor that could possible work. I had some problem with auto conversion (to normal map_iterator) which I couldn't resolve using current c++ so I didn't bother to finish it totally but I could try to post the code if you think it might interest you.

Comment: No, of course I don't need my _own_ implementation, but it serves as practice (I've left C++ for about 4 years) and is a good generic thing to have in one's toolbox (Pavel gave the key hint below) -- in particular for the cases where Boost isn't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your `K` and `V` type parameters are in a non-deducible context, so your function template is never even instantiated during overload resolution.

Look at it again:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
map_keys_iterator<K,V> map_keys(const typename std::map<K,V>::iterator &i)
```

For this to work, the C++ compiler would somehow have to walk from a specific `iterator` class to its "parent container" type - `map` in this case - to get its `K` and `V`. In general, this is impossible - after all, a particular `iterator` might be a typedef for some other class, and the actual type of argument in the call is that other class; there's no way the compiler can "retrace" it. So, per C++ standard, it doesn't even try in this case - and, more generally, in any case where you have `typename SomeType<T>::OtherType`, and `T` is a type parameter.

What you can do is make the entire parameter type a template type parameter. This requires some trickery to derive `K` and `V`, though.

```
template <typename Iterator>
map_keys_iterator<
     typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type::first_type,
     typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type::second_type
> map_keys(Iterator i)
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to repeat those two in the body of the function as well, when invoking the constructor of your type.

As a side note, iterators are generally passed by value (they're meant to be lightweight).

Comment: Aha.... so if I understand correctly, it was the "one extra layer of indirection" issue, huh? _I_ can go up and down a composite expression's types, but the compiler can only go down. I hadn't thought of checking `iterator_traits` and see it provided access to the data types. A good one. I checked it overnight and it allowed me to create a `map_keys_iterator` that worked at the first try with map, multimap and unordered_map so I'm happy now.

Comment: You can't really go up and down either, in more general cases. In this case, for example, the actual type of argument - judging from your error message - was `std::_Rb_tree_iterator`. Now imagine that all you have is that, and try to logically deduce the associated `std::map` type, and from it `K` and `V`, without guesswork :) and that's not even to mention that I can always throw a wrench into there by e.g. specializing a particular instantiation of `map` to reuse iterator type from a different one - so there'll be more than one "parent" map type for some iterator type...

Comment: OK. That clears it a lot. Fixed the code and it works as said above. I would post it but I'm sure it would be "the same but less" than what `boost::something` has brought here.