# Unclear syntax with std::tie

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdtuple

I'm just reading [a bit about tuples](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tie/?kw=tie).

Now the following syntax is not clear to me:

```
std::tie (myint, std::ignore, mychar) = mytuple;
```

It's not difficult to grasp what it does, BUT what happens from a language point of view? We are somehow assigning to the return value of a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> BUT what happens from a language point of view? We are somehow assigning to the return value of a function?

Yes, that can be valid, depending on the function's return type. There are mainly two ways in which it can be valid: firstly, the function may return an lvalue reference to an object.

```
int i;
int &f() { return i; }
int main() { f() = 1; } // okay, assigns to i
```

Secondly, functions may return user-defined types with an `=` operator implementation that can be called on rvalues:

```
struct S { void operator=(int) { } };
S f() { return {}; }
int main() { f() = 1; } // okay, calls S::operator=
```

The latter is what's happening with `std::tie`.

Comment: Note that for C++ `struct`s and `class`es, until rvalue references to `*this` showed up in C++11, could always be assigned to even if a temporary!  `operator=` would work, even if the result was discarded.  The interesting part here is that assigning to a `tie` does something *useful*.

Answer (score 5):

The return type of `std::tie(myint, std::ignore, mychar)` is
`std::tuple<int&, decltype((std::ignore)), char&>`, wherein the `int&` is a reference to `myint` and the `char&` is a reference to `mychar`.

When `mytuple` is assigned to this returned tuple-of-references, each value in `mytuple` is assigned to the respective reference stored in the returned tuple. This has the effect of updating `myint` and `mychar` in place.

```
std::tie(myint, std::ignore, mychar)             // <-- expression
std::tuple<int&, decltype((std::ignore)), char&> // <-- type

std::tie(myint, std::ignore, mychar)             = mytuple;
std::tuple<int&, decltype((std::ignore)), char&> = std::tuple<int, T, char>&;
// functions as
            std::tuple<int , T                      , char >&
//          ↓↓         =     =                        =    ↓↓
            std::tuple<int&, decltype((std::ignore)), char&>

// end result:
myint  = std::get<0>(mytuple);
mychar = std::get<2>(mytuple);
int&   = int&;
char&  = char&;
```

Comment: `decltype(std::ignore)&` (or `decltype((std::ignore))`). .

Comment: @T.C. : Indeed! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`tie` returns a tuple of references. You're assigning to that tuple, which means tuple-memberwise assignment (with the exception with `std::ignore`d fields). Because that tuple's elements are actually references, you're assigning to the tied elements instead.

Answer (score 2):

From cpp reference "Creates a tuple of lvalue references to its arguments or instances of std::ignore. "

In that sense, it's not that different from when you assign to the return value of operator [] as in

```
vec[3]=5;
```

We just have to mention that C++17 has structured bindings `auto [a,b,c] =`, and [std::ignore with structured bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673080/stdignore-with-structured-bindings)

Comment: But that's then basically an assignment to an `rvalue`, right? (Which is not forbidden in C++)

Comment: @Michael the tuple from tie is indeed an rvalue