# structured bindings and range-based-for; supress unused warning in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, unused-variables, structured-bindings

I want to traverse a map using structure bindings, ignoring the key:

```
for (auto& [unused, val] : my_map)
     do_something(val);
```

I have tried different options with gcc-7.2.0:

```
// The warning is issued
for ([[maybe_unused]] auto& [unused, val] : my_map)
      do_something(val);

// Syntax error
for (auto& [[[maybe_unused]] unused, val] : my_map)
      do_something(val);

// The same two combinations above with [[gnu::unused]].
```

It seems that the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute is not implemented yet for structure bindings.

Is there any simple solution to this? Any macro, gcc/gnu extension, or any pragma to temporarily supress that specific warning is fine to me; for example, disabling it during the whole function body where I'm using the range-based-for, because the function I'm using this is pretty short (it is basically two range-for-loops over two different maps with exact behaviour).

The (relevant) options I'm using to compile the project are:

```
-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors
```

What I have current to go on is, but that's ugly:

```
for (auto& [unused, val] : my_map)
   (void)unused, do_something(val);
```

Comment: Related: [std::ignore with structured bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673080/stdignore-with-structured-bindings).

Comment: @dfri But I cannot use `std::ignore` because it is already a declared variable, and what I have is a declaration, so, I'm introducing new names.

Comment: Yes I've only posted a related link, not a dupe mark (as explained in the link, there are currently no equivalent for `std::ignore` for structured bindings, although the standard may introduce one at a later point). A comment to one of the answers in the linked thread also recommends using `maybe_unused` for warning suppression (covering all declarations in the binding), but I don't know if this is supported (as you've tested some variations) in the context of structured bindings in a range based loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant GCC pragmas are documented [on this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

```
#include <map>

std::map<int, int> my_map;

void do_something(int);

void loop()
{
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
    for (auto & [unused, val]: my_map)
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
        do_something(val);

}
```

This is the smallest scope of the disabled warning that I could have, and still have the warning suppressed with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Answer (score 11):

It seems that you are right that the `maybe_unused` attribute is not implemented yet for structured bindings in gcc 7.2.0, but it's worth noting that it seems to be implemented for gcc 8.0 trunk (g++ 8.0.0 20171026 experimental).

Compiling using gcc 8.0 trunk, the following will emit a `-Wunused-variable` warning:

```
// warning: unused structured binding declaration [-Wunused-variable]
for (auto& [unused, val] : my_map) { }
```

Whereas this will not:

```
// no warning
for ([[maybe_unused]] auto& [unused, val] : my_map) { }
```

Peculiarly, removing `[[maybe_unused]]` but making use of at least one of the bounded variables will also not yield a warning (intended?).

```
// no warning
for (auto& [unused, val] : my_map)
{
    do_something(val);
}

// no warning
for (auto& [unused, val] : my_map)
{
    (void)unused;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Curious to know that in gcc-8 `[[maybe_unused]]` is not required at all (using only one of them is a very likely need; I think that is intended).