# Can't get std::ignore working in structured bindings in for range

Tags: c++, gcc, eclipse-cdt, structured-bindings

This code compiles and works, with an 'unused variable i' warning:

```
for(auto [camera, i]: landmark->getObservations())
  camerasToCounts[camera]++;
```

I want to ignore i, so I replaced it with `std::ignore`.  The following code doesn't compile:

```
...
#include <tuple>
...
for(auto [camera, std::ignore]: landmark->getObservations())
  camerasToCounts[camera]++;
```

with this error:

```
error: expected ‘]’ before ‘::’ token
```

and this warning:

```
warning: unused variable ‘std’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Because it is not recognizing std::ignore.

Some context:

- I'm using C++17 with gcc 7.4.0, and Eclipse CDT.
- Syntax checker shows the same error the compiler does.  This is coherent.
- Same problem in other for range in many cpp files of the same project.  It is a general problem, not a particularly bounded to that specific line.
- Just to test, this line compiles fine:

  std::ignore = 0;

so gcc recognizes std::ignore, it only fails to do so in for range.

Already read [this good question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673080/stdignore-with-structured-bindings) about ignoring in structured bindings.

Is there someone with a similar problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structured bindings declares variables<sup>1</sup> that bind to the members/elements of the thing being returned.  That means you can't use `std::ignore` since for one it is not a valid variable name and for two it is a name that has apready been declared.  If you want to ignore the result, just name the member `ignore` and don't use it like

```
for(auto [camera, ignore]: landmark->getObservations())
    camerasToCounts[camera]++;
```

---

1: It actually only creates a single variable that the return value is stored in and then the names in the square brackets are actually references the ith member of the returned object.