# How do you iterate over the keys of a std::map?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17, iteration, stdmap

I am looking for a way to iterate through the keys of a map in C++ 17. The way that I have in mind right now is based on the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281979/c-loop-through-map), the way is presented below.

```
for (auto const& [i, val] : myMap)
...
```

However, I do not need to use the value `val`, I just need the value `i`. Therefore, the piece of code `...` does not contain any call to the value `val`. Consequently, whenever I compile the code, the following warning  message appears:

```
warning: unused variable ‘val’ [-Wunused-variable]
         for (auto const& [i, val] : myMap){
                                  ^
```

What I want is to find a way to iterate through (only) the keys of the map, ignoring the values. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two options:

1. A ranged-for version of @πάνταῥεῖ 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59486096/1593077):

   ```
   for (auto const& pair : myMap) {
       auto key = pair.first;
       // etc. etc.
   }
   ```
2. Use the [ranges-v3 library](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), or [`std::ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges) in C++20, to adapt the range `myMap.begin()` and `myMap.end()` by projecting it onto its first coordinate. Then you'd write something like:

   ```
   for (auto key : std::views::keys(myMap)) {
       // etc. etc.
   }
   ```

   See also [`std::views::keys`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/keys_view).
   You can do this without ranges by creating a new container which only contains the keys, but that could be expensive for a larger map.

   <sub>(If you have weird, heavy keys, then `const auto& key` instead of `auto key`.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Sure! You can just use a traditional `for` loop with an iterator:

```
for(auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it) {
    auto i = it->first;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I was thinking about something like: `for (auto key : myMap.keys())` similarly to Java.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade There's no such equivalent in c++.

Comment: I don't see any benefit over a range based for-loop and accessing `x.first`. What's supposed to be better about manually dealing with iterators and accessing `it->first` here?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the unused warnings by casting to `void`:

```
for (auto const& [key, val] : m) {
  (void)val;  // To avoid unused warnings

  // use key
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very interesting. Can you explain to me why it works? Because I don' know exactly what this "(void) val" means.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade [What does casting to `void` really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34288844/10147399)

Answer (score 0):

How about using *Go*-like unused variable declaration with `_`:

```
for(auto const& [i, _] : myMap)
...
```

Comment: how is that supposed to help? `warning: unused variable '_' `

Comment: @Spongman in C++26, `_` is going to be treated specially and may be unused.

Answer (score -1):

for(auto const & pair : myMap)
since map internally stored element in std::pair format, hence you can access
the element by writing, pair.first; for key or pair.second; for value.

Comment: That was the solution proposed by @einpoklum. But thank you for the response.

Answer (score -4):

```
for (auto& [key, std::ignore] : m) {
  // use key
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your answer and add some description about the code. Code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Structured bindings must be identifiers; this is a *declaration*, not an assignment or reference binding.

Comment: At least make sure your code compiles before dumping it. ([It doesn't](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f96fc728ed856200).)

Comment: [std::ignore with structured bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40673080/10147399)