# C++ std::tuple ignore outputs

Tags: c++, std

I have a function:

```cpp
std::tuple<int, int> func(int x) {
    int a = x + 1;
    int b = x + 2;
    return { a, b };
}
```

and call it as:

```cpp
auto [a, b] = func(3);
```

Now I only need `b`. How can I suppress or ignore the output of `a`? Similar to MATLAB `[~, b] = func(3)`.

Comment: `auto [_, b] = func(3);` is often used. `_` (single underscore) happens to be a valid identifier.

Comment: Would [std::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore) be what you are looking for?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What if there are three, say `auto [a, b, c] = func(3)` ? I got `error: redefinition of '_'` for my real function, where I am calling `auto [_, _, c] = func(3)`.

Comment: @ExaltedBagel `std::ignore` doesn't work with structured bindings. The syntax expects a plain identifier.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I see, I could use `auto [_, __, c] = func(3)` for three outputs. But are there any more elegant ways to handle situations like this? Thanks.

Comment: You could invent a naming convention, e.g. `auto [_1, _2, c] = func(3);`. I don't believe there's anything better at the moment, any special placeholder for an ignored value.

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673080/stdignore-with-structured-bindings. In Python/C++ I typically do [_, __, (onward), b] = <tuple>

Comment: Careful - names containing double underscores are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @IgorTandetnik - didn't realize this earlier.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I believe the issue has been resolved. Would you mind expanding your comments into a small answer? Thanks again.

Comment: `auto b = std::get<1>(func(3));` if you want only one component. ;-)