# Iterate through object with no next() defined

Tags: c++, stdmap

Suppose I have objects in range `(r1,r2]` I want to insert as keys to a map. They have no iterator/next defined, but have a less than operator. How would I do this:

```
   template< class K, class V>
   void foo( K r1, K r2, V val ) {
        for(K key = r1; key < r2; ++key ) 
        { 
             mMap.insert(make_pair(key,val)); 
        }
   }
```

I cannot use `++key`.

`K` could be any type which is `copyable`, `assignable`, has `opertor<` but no `equality operator` and `arithmetic operators`.

Comment: How about `std::next`?

Comment: for that I will need iterator of key `K`.

Comment: A `std::map` always has iterators.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: There is not enough info - do you know exactly what are all the keys r1-r2 and you have them in a list? otherwise how would you know how they look like anyway?

Comment: I have updated the question with example

Comment: See my comment above. It's not clear how would you know what the next key is, unless you already have them all in a list. Be concrete, what are the keys?

Comment: Your question is unanswerable without knowing more about type K. What does it mean to iterate through an object of this type?

Comment: Try and answer this question: Given k1 and k7, the start and end of the range, how would you know k2? If you can't answer this for yourself, than we can't help.

Comment: So you want to know how to get the next object in a set when no next function is defined?  I'm going to say the answer is no, you can't.

Comment: I posted this question because the specifications given are very limited and I didn't come up with idea to get it done.

Comment: Please check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem, this isn't what you meant to ask, and can't be done.

Comment: No equality operator means you will never know what the "end" of a range of `K`'s will be. Furthermore, given two `K`'s, it's not guaranteed that they form a total order; could be that the set of all `K` is a pre-order or partial order. So basically the notion of ranges of `K` is undefined. I agree with @kabanus that your problem is higher up the call chain.

Comment: End of range is solved by `opertor<` which is available. The problem is going to next element.

Answer (score 1):

The iterability of a key is irrelevant, the map implements the iteration over the set of keys. See something close in [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap#1066607):

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...;

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    // ...
}
```

or closer in [Iterate keys in a C++ map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443793/iterate-keys-in-a-c-map#1443798):

```
for(std::map<Key,Val>::iterator iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); ++iter)
{

}
```

Comment: ... or just `for (const auto& keyvalue : myMap) { ... keyvalue.first ... keyvalue.second ... }`

Comment: Actually I want to insert keys from range `(r1, r2]`. 

for(K key = r1; key < r2; ++key ) { map.insert(make_pair(key,val)); }

I cannot use `++key`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit rusty - and not completely swimming through the new syntax. @has, your question is very unclear. Remove any references to a map in your question, and just ask how to iterate through a range of object with no iteration defined.

Comment: @has if `K` is not iterable, then it makes no sense to talk about a range of `K`'s. You're going to have to tell us more about your `K` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iterator from std::map class

you get it with [Begin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/)

you can write a for loop with that iterator from type `std::map<type,type>::iterator`
 and then use all your operators as expected