# C++ 03 equivalent of C++11 lambda

Tags: c++11, lambda, c++03

Referring to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517561/why-set-symmetric-difference-fails-to-work-with-comparater/43522078#43522078), as the explanation is required in detail.
How is the following code snippet working, fundamental and C++ 03 equivalent ?

```
 auto get_option_name = [](const std::pair<const std::string, std::string>& p) -> const std::string& {
    return p.first;
 };
```

Comment: it's a functor, ie an object that work like a function. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's equivalent to:

```
class Extractor {
    // Definition of "function call" operator, to use instance
    // of this class like a function
    const std::string& operator()(const std::pair<const std::string, std::string>& p) {
        return p.first;
    }
};

Extractor get_option_name;
```

More information on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) or on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Answer (score 2):

@Garf365's answer is the best. A lambda and a class like that one really are the most similar - you can use them just like callable functions, and pass around pointers and references to them.

However, you may also want to learn about using **function templates** to do this work during compile-time, especially when passing them as a parameter to another template, as in using the boost library.

I was curious if there was an improvement in the complexity of the code the compiler produced by using a function template, and there was!

Look for yourself:

- [Using a "function object" or "functor" class](https://godbolt.org/g/eBxWV6) (or whatever they are called) - is 187 lines of assembly from GCC, and 237 lines of assembly from clang.
- [Using a function template](https://godbolt.org/g/f4Wuvq) - only 65 lines of assembly from GCC, and 84 from clang. **That's a reduction by a factor of 300%!**

Thank you for asking the question and leading me to look into it!

Comment: This answer is **incorrect** - the reason your function object results in longer assembly is that you are converting `pair<string, string>` to `pair<const string, string>` in `Extractor::operator()` which requires a copy. If you remove the `const` and make a temporary `Extractor` the resulting code is identical.

Comment: @rlbond I'm always happy to have a better way shown to me. Please share your answer, so everyone can see the best way to do it. It's been 3.5 years (to the day!) since I wrote the answer, so I can't recall all the details (I remember I was writing code for GCC 4.4.7 at the time, so I'm not sure why I used a different version in answering this question. Oh well!)