# Map iterator that points directly to the key or value, not the pair<key, value>

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, templates, iterator

In my program, I have a template class that can take as arguments any type of container, like std::vector, std::map, etc.

The goal is that my class can work with both vector iterators and map iterators. Right now it works with vector iterators, for example they do stuff with the vector iterators as arguments. Small example:

```
template <class T>
class Example
{
private:

public:
    Example() {}
    void someMethod(typename T::iterator it)
    {
        cout << *it;
    }
};
```

If I use `Example< vector<int> > example`, and use `someMethod` with some iterator, the method will just print an `int` from the vector.

But if I will use `Example < map<int, int> >` and pass a `map<int, int>::iterator` as argument in `someMethod` it will not work, because I would have to change the `*it` in `someMethod` to `it->first` or `it->second` (depending on what I want to print, key or value).

My question: is there a way I could pass a map iterator that would actually be an iterator to the key / value so I don't have to touch any method in my class?

Comment: [Are you looking for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262398/7691729)? There isn't anything like this in STL unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. I guess I have to write something like a custom iterator, right?

Comment: @Quimby : There is as of C++20: [`std::views::keys`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/keys_view) and [`std::views::values`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/values_view)

Comment: First you can always define an `operator <<` for pair. But that's not really flexible. Better to add a second argument to `someMethod` for printing `*it`. You can specify a default so you only have to give the second argument when `*it` doesn't have an `operator <<` itself or you want a custom printer.